# NSXMLParser parsing more items if a button was clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to parse a url currently with only 25 'items'. These items are then being shown in a UITableView. However I would like to know how I could load the next 25 items and then add them to the UITableView by using the method insert row at index path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite getting you.. correct me if Im wrong.. if you want to append the object to current table then just add the objects to nsmutablearrat and reload the table.
and if you want to add the next 25 items at specific location use nsmutable array method. addObjectAtIndex [Class References from Apple Dev](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and reload the table.

Comment: I want to parse the next 25 objects in an XML file and then add them to a NSMutableArray. But I don't know how to parse the next 25 objects.